# I am trying to achieve a directory URL using parameters with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, structure

I would like to show certain content on my website. I choose the content based on a URL parameter, like page=about. This works well, and my URL looks like example.com/mysite/index.php?page=about. My issue is that I would like my URL to read example.com/mysite/about, where the last part is the name of the page parameter.

I am attempting to do this through htaccess. This is my exact code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I see no change on my page nor to the URL structure. The URL still reads ...index.php?page=about. Am I doing something wrong? I tried this a bunch of different ways and I still get the same result. I also tried simply doing this, with no change:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

I didn't think it was working, so I tried a redirect to some other site and it worked. Therefore, the htaccess file is getting read and able to function.

Any assistance would be helpful!

Thank you,
BP

Comment: mod_rewrite’s job here is to rewrite the request that reaches the server, internally. Changing what the links in your HTML code point to in the first place - that is still _your_ responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these 2 rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(mysite)/index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mysite/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?page=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried it and my site showed no change in the URL structure. Of course I replaced 'mysite' with my actual site, but it still didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: What is full URL you entered in browser?

Comment: Nevermind!! This worked perfectly. I withdraw my comment. :) Thank you very much. I just needed to make an adjustment to the URL I was going to in order to run it properly.

Comment: Thanks, this code is working very well. I am now attempting to put a directory structure in it, such that "page=about&dir=category" would yield "/category/page". I'm new to HTACCESS and I'm having a bit of a difficult time adding that extra parameter in. I'd certainly appreciate any help you could give.

Comment: @BDP: Please open a new question with examples and you will get help.